# Efficient Record Construction in Coq: Is Direct Proof Inclusion Possible?

Tags: coq

I want to define a small record in Coq which also includes certain conditions. In addition I want a definition to create a record in an easy way. Here is my approach:

```
Require Import Arith.

(* Define the qn record with conditions for q and n *)
Record qn := {
    q : nat;
    q_ge_2 : leb 2 q = true; (* Ensuring q is greater or equal than 2 *)
    n : nat;
    n_ge_1 : leb 1 n = true  (* Ensuring n is greater or equal than 1 *)
  }.

(* A support function to create instances of qn more conveniently *)
Definition make_qn (q n: nat) (Hq : leb 2 q = true) (Hn : leb 1 n = true) : qn :=
  {| q := q; q_ge_2 := Hq; n := n; n_ge_1 := Hn |}.

(* Examples of qn *)
Example qn_example1 : qn := make_qn 2 1 (eq_refl true) (eq_refl true).
Example qn_example2 : qn := make_qn 3 5 (eq_refl true) (eq_refl true).
Example qn_example3 : qn := make_qn 4 2 (eq_refl true) (eq_refl true).
```

I tried already some different approaches - also to define the qn record, e.g. using Prop instead of bool.

Is there a way to simplify the `make_qn` definition to directly include the proofs? E.g. to use it like

```
Example qn_simple1 : qn := make_qn 2 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this definition of `qn` (where I have renamed few things for convenience):

```
(* Define [qn] with conditions for [q] and [n]. *)
Record qn := mkQn
{
  qn_q : nat ;
  qn_n : nat ;
  qn_q_ge_2 : qn_q >= 2 ;
  qn_n_ge_1 : qn_n >= 1 ;
}.
```

With the premise that all functions in Coq must be total, we can in fact prove that there is *no* "short-cutting `qn` constructor" as per your question, i.e. that there is no (total) function that, given *arbitrary* `q` and `n`, returns a `qn` such that its `qn_q` = `q` and `qn_n` = `n`:

```
(* The type of "short-cutting [qn] constructors". *)
Definition MkQnSc := forall q n : nat,
  { i : qn | i.(qn_q) = q /\ i.(qn_n) = n }.

(* [MkQnSc] is empty! *)
Lemma no_MkQnSc : MkQnSc -> False.
Proof.
  unfold MkQnSc.
  intros F.
  destruct (F 0 0) as [[q n Hq Hn] [Eq _]].
  simpl in Eq.
  rewrite Eq in Hq.
  inversion Hq.
Qed.
```

Incidentally, a possible approach to a "short-cutting `qn` constructor" (as per your question) is by having `option qn` as the return type, though of course that just moves the goalpost, as then the need becomes that of pattern-matching on the returned `option` / proving we got a `Some` vs `None`.

That said, a way to mitigate the inconvenience of having to supply proof terms every time in the constructor (also mentioned by @Villetaneuse in a comment to his answer) is the use of *notations with tactics*, which can indeed be used to construct terms, though cannot be used in pattern matching (I am not aware of other significant differences, at least not in this case):

```
From Coq Require Import Lia.

Notation mkQnSc q n :=
  (mkQn q n ltac:(lia) ltac:(lia))
  (only parsing).

Example ex_qn_2_1 : qn := mkQnSc 2 1.  (* OK *)

Fail Example ex_qn_0_0 := mkQnSc 0 0.
  (* OK: Cannot find witness *)

Fail Example ex_qn q n := mkQnSc q n.
  (* OK: Cannot find witness *)

Fail Definition is_qn_2_1 (i : qn) : Prop :=
  match i with
  | mkQnSc 2 1 => True
  | _          => False
  end.  (* ERROR: Quotations not supported in patterns *)

Definition is_qn_2_1 (i : qn) : Prop :=
  match i with
  | mkQn 2 1 _ _ => True
  | _            => False
  end.  (* OK *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

When your proofs are (semi)decidable, you can use the magic of dependent types:

```
Require Import Arith.

(* Define the qn record with conditions for q and n *)
Record qn := {
    q : nat;
    q_ge_2 : leb 2 q = true; (* Ensuring q is greater or equal than 2 *)
    n : nat;
    n_ge_1 : leb 1 n = true  (* Ensuring n is greater or equal than 1 *)
  }.

(* A support function to create instances of qn more conveniently *)
Local Open Scope bool_scope.
Definition make_qn (q n: nat) : if leb 2 q && leb 1 n then qn else True :=
  match leb 2 q as leb2q, leb 1 n as leb1n
        return leb 2 q = leb2q -> leb 1 n = leb1n -> if leb2q && leb1n then qn else True
  with
  | true, true => fun Hq Hn => {| q := q; q_ge_2 := Hq; n := n; n_ge_1 := Hn |}
  | _, _ => fun _ _ => I
  end eq_refl eq_refl.

(* Examples of qn *)
Example qn_example1 : qn := make_qn 2 1.
Example qn_example2 : qn := make_qn 3 5.
Example qn_example3 : qn := make_qn 4 2.
```

Note the type of `make_qn`: it only returns `qn` when the proofs can be filled.

---

You can push this even further if you really want: you could port any tactic to something like [Rtac](https://gmalecha.github.io/reflections/2016/rtac-technical-overview) and use typeclasses or canonical structures for reification, so that you can check the result of running an Rtac tactic in the return type.  But at this point you might as well use the trick with tactics in notations that Villetaneuse describes.

And as Julio Di Egidio explained, a simply-typed `make_qn` is inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you, I am still realizing how expressive these types can be!  That said, a bit of a drawback with that code is that `make_qn 0 0` still type-checks (which I'm taking to be another instance of "all functions are total"), while my `mkQnSc 0 0` with a notation gives a tactic failure. -- I am going to add a couple of examples to my answer in that sense.

Comment: I have just now realized you had said that... :)  Indeed, thanks for the link to Rtac.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to simplify your code.

1. I use `Prop` instead of `bool` because `lia` likes `Prop` better, but `bool` could also be kept with other tools to prove the inequalities (or even simple computation).
2. Instead of defining `make_qn` outside the record, I give a name to the record constructor.
3. I use `ltac:(tactic)` to construct proof terms in the examples.

It's probably not perfect (for instance, equality for this record has to use some form of proof irrelevance).

I don't think there is a magical solution to build elements without giving proof terms.

```
Require Import Arith.

(* Define the qn record with conditions for q and n *)
(* I have changed bool with Prop. *)
Record qn := MakeQn {
    q : nat;
    q_ge_2 : q >= 2; (* Ensuring q is greater or equal than 2 *)
    n : nat;
    n_ge_1 : n >= 1  (* Ensuring n is greater or equal than 1 *)
  }.

Require Import Lia.
(* Examples of qn *)
Example qn_example1 : qn := MakeQn 2 ltac:(lia) 1 ltac:(lia).
Example qn_example2 : qn := MakeQn 3 ltac:(lia) 5 ltac:(lia).
Example qn_example3 : qn := MakeQn 4 ltac:(lia) 2 ltac:(lia).
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. I tried this also (see question) - but was not able to eliminate the need to provide the explicit proofs. You wrote "I don't think there is a magical solution to build elements without giving proof terms.": can you give an argument for this? If the simple solution does not exists, I need using the more complex one - but want to eliminate first, that a simpler solution exists.

Comment: If you really insist on it, you could define an abbreviation, this would work in these very simple cases...

`Notation MakeQnSimple q n := (MakeQn q ltac:(lia) n ltac:(lia)) (only parsing).`

`Example qn_example1' : qn := MakeQnSimple 2 1.`

Comment: But in general, since you there are proof terms in your record, I cannot think of a solution in which Coq would guess how to prove these inequalities by itself (and reject the constructor application when they do not hold).

Comment: The comments lead into the right direction - but the answer from @julio is better and complete.